# Django - Query for any objects where any item from list is in ManytoMany field

Tags: django, model, get, many-to-many

I have a model in Django that has a ManytoMany field called 'accepted_insurance'. I have a form that submits a get request with a query string that contains of list of insurance providers. I am trying to write a query that says 'If any of the items from the query string list, are in the ManytoMany field list, than filter those objects.'. Is there a Django query shortcut for this ? I attempted to use 'contains', but I got a type error that the related field got an invalid lookup, and I'm sure that would simply say if the list contained the list.

models.py

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    extension = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(default='', null=True, blank=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    cost_per_session = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    accepts_insurance = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    accepted_insurance = models.ManyToManyField('Insurance', blank=True)
    payment_methods = models.ManyToManyField('PaymentMethod', blank=True)
```

request.GET

```
http://localhost:8004/directory/?search=timothy&insurance=cigna,aetna,optum_health,united_behavioral,blue_cross_blue_shield

<QueryDict: {'insurance': ['cigna,aetna,optum_health,united_behavioral,blue_cross_blue_shield'], 'search': ['timothy']}>
```

views.py Query

```
for param in request.GET:
    if param.lower() == 'insurance':
        all_providers = all_providers.filter(accepted_insurance__contains=param)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__in` is the operator you need here.

However you have a few other problems. Firstly there is no need to loop through the querydict; it is a dict, you can access it via key.

Secondly, you currently have a single string; you need to split it into a list of strings with the `split(',')` method.

Thirdly, you need to actually filter against a field on the Insurance model - presumably it has a "name" field.

So:

```
insurance = request.GET.get('insurance', '').split(',')
all_providers = all_providers.filter(accepted_insurance__name__in=insurance)
```

Comment: So if accepted insurance has two objects with the titles 'Blue Cross Blue Shield', and 'Cigna', will it try to see if both of those titles are in the insurance dictionary ?

Comment: No. It will match any Provider which has any of the names in the list in its accepted_insurance field.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Daniel ! Some of the query shortcuts sound a little counter intuitive at first, but if it works it works.

Comment: Note that if a provider matches more than one item in the list, it might appear in the output twice; add `.distinct()` to the query to prevent that.

Comment: Is __in case insensitive ?